# Insert Strings that contain “ ` ” or “ ' ” to the database table - Qt

Tags: mysql, qt, qsqlquery

I have to insert some strings to MySQL database.
The problem is that every time I use " ` " or " ' " it causes errors in the QSqlquery execution.
How can I prevent this?

Comment: definitely you need to read about SQL injection. mavroprovato gave you a perfect answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use bind variables when running your query and you will never have problems with special characters in SQL queries. Here is an example from the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsql/qsqlquery.html):

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("INSERT INTO person (id, forename, surname) "
              "VALUES (:id, :forename, :surname)");
query.bindValue(":id", 1001);
query.bindValue(":forename", "Bart");
query.bindValue(":surname", "Simpson");
query.exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

` and ' are comment in SQL, you have to "protect" them with a backslash \ like so

```
Select bla
From blo
where name = "some \`test\`"
```

Comment: 'Protecting" is usually referred to as 'escaping with'

Comment: @TimZaman you're right but my english was quite bad, feel free to edit the post :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add escape sequence to add such type of special characters like `'`, `` ` ``, `\`, `"`

Please add them by adding `\` before them.

e.g.

For `'`  use `\'`

For `"`  use `\"`

For `\`  use `\\`

For `` ` ``  use `` \` ``

Answer (score -2):

```
// Connect
$link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')
    OR die(mysql_error());

// Query
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='%s' AND password='%s'",
            mysql_real_escape_string($user),
            mysql_real_escape_string($password));
```

in php, You can use mysql_real_escape_string function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Hope will help you!

Comment: How does this help exactly?